# How to expand a type specifier inside a `declare`?

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I'm using Common Lisp, and I have multiple functions use the same type of data, and I use `declare` to specify the type of symbols like this:

```
(defun foo (x)
  (declare (type single-float x))
  ...)

(defun bar (x y)
  (declare (type single-float x y))
  ...)
```

Now I want to store `single-float` into a custom symbol like `changable-float` so that I can easily change all the types of these functions (e.g., from `single-float` to `double-float`). I have tried these code but it not works:

```
(defvar changeable-float 'single-float)

(defun foo (x)
  (declare (type changeable-float x))
  ...)

(defun bar (x y)
  (declare (type changeable-float x y))
  ...)
```

How can I implement this idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `DEFTYPE` to define a type.

```
CL-USER 41 > (deftype foo () 'integer)
FOO

CL-USER 42 > (typep 3 'foo)
T

CL-USER 43 > (typep "33" 'foo)
NIL
```